# Custom headers not logging in HAProxy

Tags: haproxy

I am trying to set and log custom headers in HAProxy in order to get data so I can set up our DDoS/Anti Abuse configs.

The trouble I am having is that I can set headers, and I can capture headers not set by HAProxy (eg: Accept-Language) but I cannot capture/log headers that I set. They just show up blank in the log. The config below I have simplified everything as much as possible and it still won't log the custom headers.

I have all of this in a single front end.

```
frontend WEBSERVER
    bind 111.222.333.444:80
    option forwardfor
    option httplog

    .......

    http-request add-header X-IP %ci
    http-request add-header X-Custom-Header pizza


    capture request header X-IP len 64
    capture request header X-Custom-Header len 5
    capture request header Accept-Language len 64

    default_backend WEB-FARM
```

My logs end up looking like this:

```
10.0.0.1:62291 [20/Oct/2015:12:52:26.112] WEBSERVER WEB_FARM/WEB-1 5/0/49/50/315 200 16875 - - ---- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 {||en-US,en;q=0.8} "GET /media/title.png HTTP/1.1"
```

Comment: Surely the client IP is already right there in the log? Anyway, `capture request header` works at the time the request is received, not after some processing (i.e. `add-header`) is done.

Comment: Perfect, this was the missing piece of the puzzle. I created a back end that proxies the request to a new front end that does the logging. Working fine now.

Something like (https://github.com/jvehent/haproxy-aws)

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what version of HAProxy you're using, but in 1.6.x, the [http-request](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#http-request) keyword now has a `capture` argument that should do the trick for you.

You use it the exact same way as you would `capture request header`:

```
frontend WEBSERVER
  bind 111.222.333.444:80
  option forwardfor
  option httplog

  .......

  http-request add-header X-IP %ci
  http-request add-header X-Custom-Header pizza


  http-request capture hdr(X-IP) len 64
  http-request capture hdr(X-Custom-Header) len 5
  capture request header Accept-Language len 64

  default_backend WEB-FARM
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This took me a whole day until I found this. I did not grasp from the official documentation, that the regular `capture request header` would not work for my custom added headers. I would upvote this twice, if I could.